# htaccess force www, remove "index.php", create clean url and add trailing backslash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a small informational webpage that can be viewed in both Japanese and English (Japanese is the default). It's technically only one php file, just switching language of content based on URL.

I want to force www and force a trailing slash on both language versions. The default Japanese page I just want to just show the main site URL as below:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/
```

Then on the English version, I want it to go to a URL like the one below:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/en/
```

I can't figure out how to force the backward slash, and when I test it with something like http://www.mydomain.com/en/index.php,
it changes it to http://www.mydomain.com/en?en.

My current .htaccess file looks like what I have below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Redirect all non-www traffic to the www version of site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Remove 'index.php' from requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

#Force clean URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/(index\.php)?\?l=(en)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1\/%3\/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert this new rule just below first `www` rule for forcing trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```